# Use monitor more than maximum resolution safe.?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have new monitor for my laptop.

First, I don't know my leptop resolution is bigger than my monitor max resolution, but after setting it's working fine with same resolution as my laptop.

But when I want configure the display in monitor I found this
[Resolution in below left is more than maximum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdqFD.jpg)

It's working fine after more than 20 hours, but I just want to ask if this safe for monitor and why it's have more than maximum.?

BTW I use windows 10 and Intel VGA, I setting the resolution from Intel Control Panel.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that it just downscales the resolution to make it fit. It shouldn't cause any harm.

Comment: Yeah, I hope this not an issue, but i still want to know why this monitor have more resolution than it's max. Because the downscales not really big i think.

Answer (score 0):

For digital monitors, [using a higher resolution than the monitor can handle is safe](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=748024), but the display might be blurry compared to using the physical native resolution, or it might not display anything at all, if it shuts down temporarily.

Old [CRT displays could be damaged](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6614/can-the-wrong-sync-frequency-really-destroy-a-crt-monitor) by using the incorrect display parameters, particularly scan rates (frequency).

Comment: After many days using it the monitor is fine, and in my case it's not blur, it just have litle bigger icon than may leptop use. Thanks for the answer..